# ActiveReports cells breaking over two lines

Tags: activereports

I am using ActiveReports 7 and exporting to XLS with a very large amount of rows and columns.  The report "randomly" splits large cells over two rows.  I say randomly, if i run the same report multiple times it will always break on the same row but there's nothing special on the row.

We are using

```
exporter.UseCellMerging = True
exporter.AutoRowHeight = True
exporter.RemoveVerticalSpace = True
```

Are there any other properties I need to include in order to prevent this from happening?

Answer (score 0):

Large cells will split over two rows when the TextBox is splitting in the rendered view of the report as well. This is the design behavior. The textBoxes(or other controls in ActiveReports) split over pages when their is no space on the current page to display the full control. If you don't want these textBoxes to split over pages, please set the KeepTogether property of the Section in which the respective textBox is situated in, to True.

Moreover, ActiveReports 7 is a legacy product. We suggest you to try with the latest version i.e. ActiveReports 16 (https://www.grapecity.com/activereportsnet/download).
You can also post your query on our forums - https://www.grapecity.com/forums/ar-dev
or create a ticket through our support system - https://www.grapecity.com/my-account/my-support